# Symfony2: Always use @Assert entity annotations for form validation

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

SF2 can guess the type of an element in the form. And it can guess the correct values for (among others) the `required` and the `max_length` attributes. But it only will try to do the latter when guessing the field type, i.e.: when the field type is not specified explicitly.

Apart from the fact that this does not seem very sensible to me, I wonder if there is some way to make SF2 use `@Assert` annotations such as  `@Assert\NotBlank` and `@Assert\Length` to set these options, *even if the field type is specified explicitly*. Or to phrase it differently: I would like the form to use as many of the @Assert annotations in the entity as possible, regardless of whether the type is guessed or not.

If it makes a difference: I’m using Symfony 2.7

Comment: I don't follow. `required` and `max_length` are client side validations. `@Assert` are server-side. What is stopping you from using `@Assert`?

Comment: Client side validation and server side validation should be in sync. (There may be cases where this is not desirable, but usually it is.) I makes no sense to force a field to not be empty on the client-side, if it is allowed to be empty on the server side (ditto for max. length). Of course nothing stops me from using `@Assert`, but I would prefer if Symfony automatically additionally used the `@Assert` annotations also for the client side – instead of adding arbitrary client side validations I never asked for.